# Is it possible to "Debug View Hierarchy" in Xcode for an app extension?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to debug the view hierarchy in an app extension, but I don't get anything useful.

Are there any limitations to using this feature with extensions?

If not, what could I possibly be doing wrong?
I have the feeling there might be since the app is actually running inside a third party's UI.  Would this be to keep people from "looking inside someone else's app"?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it seems not possible at this time. On Xcode8 iOS10, it shows nothing for keyboard extension.

An alternative choice is [Reveal](https://revealapp.com/). On latest version, it supports App Extension. Actually it is what I am using right now.